# C# Using Linq to entities to get fields from joined table (Lambda?)

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have two related tables, billing_transactions and billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.  The second is the many to the firsts one.
There are only two type of records in the second table, I need to know in my query if it has none, one or both of them.  The types are a service_code_id = 1 (meaning this delivery is a residential delivery) or a 2 (meaning it has a dish machine) - A delivery can have both.

I have tried the following, but it returns two records if there are two entries (obviously).

I assume I can do this with a Lambda expression, but I have tried multiple way of writing it so far.  I have searched using every search term I can think of as well...I know this is probably a dup...but I just can't find it.

The where is just to narrow it down to some records I know have related items.

```
var gridData = (from d in db.billing_transactions
                join a in db.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge on d.Id equals a.billing_transaction_id into Inners
                from sd in Inners.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where (d.Id > 954 && d.Id < 958)
                select new
                {
                    d.base_amount,
                    d.Id,
                    residential = sd.service_code_id == 1 ? "Res" : "no res" ,
                    dishMachine = sd.service_code_id == 2 ? "Dish" : "No dish",
                    drivers_name = d.stop_details.driver_details.first_name + " " + d.stop_details.driver_details.last_name,
                    placeholder1 = "",
                    select_col = 0
                }).Distinct().ToArray();
```

So this is what the data would look like:

```
billing_transaction : Id - 99
billing_transaction_accessorial_charge (record1) billing_transaction_id - 99, service_code_id - 1

billing_transaction_accessorial_charge (record2) billing_transaction_id - 99, service_code_id - 2
```

Returned dataset with something like:

```
Id=99 residential = Res, dishMachine = Dish
```

Or, if there was no record with a service_code_id of 2 then it would have dishMachine = "no dish"

Comment: You seem to be falling victim to the transliteration mistake as [described by J. Albarahi](https://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx).

Comment: Your right...I do not need a join, thank you for the prod in the right direction and the useful link.  That helped me it figured out.  I will post the answer when it lets me, or just post your link as a answer as it pretty much did it.

Comment: residential = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.Where(p => p.service_code_id == 1),

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed the right direction by Aluan -- Thank you.

The below does what I need:

```
 var gridData = (from d in db.billing_transactions
                        where (d.Id > 954 && d.Id < 958)
                        select new
                        {
                            d.base_amount,
                            d.Id,
                            dishmachine = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.Where (p => p.service_code_id == 2),
                            residential = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.Where(p => p.service_code_id == 1),
                            drivers_name = d.stop_details.driver_details.first_name + " " + d.stop_details.driver_details.last_name,
                            placeholder1 = "",
                            select_col = 0
                        }
                      ).ToArray();
```